# KeyError: 'datapath' with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyerror

I am getting an error when trying to run code and am unsure how to solve the issue. I am unsure what this datapath is and the error is coming straight from the matplotlib package. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the error I am getting:

```
running API pyqt5
using configuration at /home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/image_analyzer.conf
no Pyro installed. Use dummy event handler.
/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/mplwidget.py:123: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The _init_toolbar method was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later. Please fully initialize the toolbar in your subclass' __init__; a fully empty _init_toolbar implementation may be kept for compatibility with earlier versions of Matplotlib.
  super(Toolbar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 5, in <module>
    dmw, app, reuseapp = main.run_app()
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/main.py", line 552, in run_app
    dmw = DesignerMainWindow()
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/main.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/gui.py", line 333, in setupUi
    self.main_area = self.setup_main_area(self.main_widget)
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/gui.py", line 306, in setup_main_area
    center_area = self.setup_center_area(main_area)
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/gui.py", line 196, in setup_center_area
    self.main_image_plot = MplWidget(self.tabs[0])
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/mplwidget.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.mpl_toolbar = Toolbar(self.figCanvas, self)
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/mplwidget.py", line 123, in __init__
    super(Toolbar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 681, in __init__
    NavigationToolbar2.__init__(self, canvas)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2913, in __init__
    init()
  File "/home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/mplwidget.py", line 140, in _init_toolbar
    self.basedir = os.path.join(mpl.rcParams["datapath"], "images")
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 623, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'datapath'
```

start.py file:

```
#!/bin/env python
from qimageanalyser import main
import sys

dmw, app, reuseapp = main.run_app()
if "app" in globals() and not reuseapp:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

image_analyzer.conf file (I have to write more text to post this so I am writing more text here):

```
[Analysis Functions]
fitter = gaussian
analyser = absorption2
clearonnewrun = False

[General]
atom = Li6
nPics = 2
default_ref_roi_xi = 0
default_ref_roi_yi = 0
default_ref_roi_xf = 40
default_ref_roi_yf = 100

[Gui]
colorscale = jet

[Guppy]
pixelarea = 329.28e-12
magnification = 0.33

[Manta]
pixelarea = 64e-12
magnification = 2.5

[None]
pixelarea = 100e-12
magnification = 1

[Li6]
crosssection = 2.14949894091e-13
clebsch = 0.5
mass = 6

[Li7]
crosssection = 2.14949894091e-13
clebsch = 0.5
mass = 7

[Na]
crosssection = 1.6564257603715025E-13
clebsch = 1
mass = 23
```

Comment: might it be something in your configuration file?   You haven't included your code, so there's not much to go by.

Comment: Which configuration file? I could post the gui.py file and the mplwidget.py file but they are pretty long

Comment: This one: /home/Desktop/Arbeit/image_analyzer_files/imageanalyser/qimageanalyser/image_analyzer.conf.  What is ```start.py```?

Comment: I just updated the post with star.py and image_analyzer.conf. I'm not sure what could be wrong in the .conf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mpl.rcParams["datapath"]` was deprecated: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/16417

Solution is to use

```
mpl.get_data_path()
```

instead of

```
mpl.rcParams["datapath"]
```